# How works k command in windbg

Tags: x86, windbg, callstack

I am studying a Windows x86 binary in windbg.
When i debug a function, in can see the call stack with « k » command.

My question is: how works windbg internaly to get this call stack ?

I was thinking it works with ebp register and stack frame.

But some functions does not push esp/ebp in the begining. So how works k command in this case ?

Answer (score 1):

It uses the *ebp*, *esp* and *eip* registers for each stack frame unless you explicitly pass them to the **k** command yourself. If those registers aren't set correctly then usually you'll get a inaccurate stack trace or nothing at all.

You might find this [article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190206-00/?p=101034) to be useful as well.